# How can I change the default theme in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

### Background

I would like to change the theme that ggplot uses, but I am having difficulty understanding the `theme_update()` documentation and examples.

I am using `align_plots()` to place a boxplot over a density plot, but I found none of that code was causing the error, and was left with the minimal example. I suspect that the error is caused by the use of `theme_blank()`, but I am not sure why it occurs or how I can fix it.

So, here I provide a minimal reproducible example of an error that I am getting:

```
library(ggExtra)
align.plots(qplot(1))
```

But it breaks after I update the theme:

```
newtheme <- theme_update(axis.text.y = theme_blank(),
                         axis.line = theme_blank(),
                         axis.title.x = theme_blank(), 
                         axis.title.y = theme_blank(),
                         axis.ticks.x = theme_blank(),
                         panel.grid.major = theme_blank(),
                         panel.grid.minor = theme_blank(),
                         panel.border = theme_blank(),
                         axis.color.y = 'white')
align.plots(qplot(1))
```

This gives the error:

```
Error in UseMethod("validGrob") : 
  no applicable method for 'validGrob' applied to an object of class "NULL"
In addition: Warning message:
In editThisGrob(grob, specs) : Slot 'vp' not found
```

### Questions:

1. What causes this error?
2. Where can I get more information on using `?theme_update()`? I got this far on the ggplot documentation, and can't find the answer at the [ggplot website](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2), although the closest that I got was the [polishing.r](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/book/polishing.r) script

### note:

I get the same error with a solution based on [Hadley's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3824412/ggplot2-use-options-for-multiple-plots/3824489#3824489) for another question.

```
opt <- opts(...)
align.plots(qplot(1) + opt)
```

where `...` is the contents of `theme_update()` above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be considered a bug in ggExtra::align.plots(). This function computes the size of different elements of a ggplot, such as y-axis label and legend, and aligns the plots accordingly to have the plot panels on top of each other. If you set your theme to use theme_blank() for some of those graphical elements, the function gets confused as the underlying grob (ggplot2:::.zeroGrob) isn't quite like other grobs.

While it might be fixable (*), I think you'd be better off considering other options:

- use a dummy facetting variable to have ggplot2 automatically align the two panels
- use gridExtra::grid.arrange() or plain grid viewports to have the two plots on top of each other; since you removed the elements that may offset the plot positions, there should be no problem.

(*): now fixed, try

```
   source("http://ggextra.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/R/align.r")
```

Comment: Hey, Baptiste! The new align.r appears to be behind a password wall. Any advice?

Comment: this package is deprecated; I'd suggest you use [facetting instead](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/Align-two-plots-on-a-page)

Answer (score 7):

I don't know why this works, but it does. Just insert the line `theme_set(newtheme)` before you call align.plots.

Comment: thanks. I tried this before; it makes a plot, but the plot is in the default `theme_grey()` rather than with the `theme_blank()` options that are in `newtheme`

Comment: @DavidLeBauer Thank you a lot! It got changed somehow and I can restore it like that `theme_set(theme_grey())`