# a global x/y-axis on multiple ggplot2 figures

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have four ggplot2 objects to be arranged in a 2-by-2 layout figure, and I refer to this function [here](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Multiple_graphs_on_one_page_%28ggplot2%29/): the `multiplot` function works well if each of my four plots is provided. For example:

```
multiplot(p1, p2, p3, p4, cols=2, layout=matrix(seq(1,4), nr=2, byrow=TRUE))
```

However, in each of the plot, I suppress the x- and y-axis labels, because they are identical and **I hope to put a global x-axis label and a global y-axis label on the 2-by-2 big panel**. Is there a way to modify the `multiplot` function to achieve this?

There is a related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11076567/plot-a-legend-and-well-spaced-universal-y-axis-and-main-titles-in-grid-arrange), but it seems to be outdated. It also provides a reproducible example. Thank you!

**Update**

Thanks Scott for the solution. One more question while I add the axis labels: how can I control the margin of the entire figure? I tried to use `plot.margin` in `theme`, but the problem of not showing the complete labels still remain. Please see the attached screenshot below:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `grid.text` to add labels wherever you want them by passing into the `multiplot` function. For example:

https://gist.github.com/sckott/8444444

And you could easily add in a parameter to `multiplot` to pass in placement of the labels.

Sorry, there's a lot of code, so it's all in the gist instead...

Comment: thank you so much! one more question about margins. Please see my update in OP :)

Comment: That should just be the placement of the labels via `grid.text`. Try the updated function in my gist. I added params for x and y positions of each label